# JavaScript and conditional formatting based on localStorage contents

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm writing a GreaseMonkey script to make some much-needed enhancements to my employer's internal job search website.

The loop I've included here iterates through all the rows in a table returned by a job search. I'm adding icons to the left side of each row to track communication, acceptance, and rejection. The data is logged in the browser localStorage as a JSON object converted to a string. An example localStorage entry looks like this:

```
job_12345 = '{"accept":"9/3/2017, 6:50 PM","reject":"9/3/2017, 6:50 PM"}'
```

In the below function, lstore is a localStorage key+value like the above example. The loop works fine until I try to add in a bit of conditional formatting that shows a "disabled" icon (really just 50% opacity) for job actions that don't exist in localStorage.

It's that three-line IF statement near the bottom of my loop that I just cannot figure out. It works on the first time in the array, and then the array simply breaks and the function ends.

```js
function checkRows() {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("jstat") != null) {
        clearInterval(startIt2);
        var jobs2 = document.getElementById('results').getElementsByClassName('jrow');

        for (var j = 0; j < jobs2.length; j++) {
            // conditional formatting by status
            var job_status = jobs2[j].getElementsByClassName("jstat")[0].innerText;
            job_status = job_status.toLowerCase();
            job_status = job_status.replace(/ /g, "_");

            // apply conditional class to each row
            jobs2[j].classList.add(job_status);

            // get job id for shortcut buttons
            var jid = jobs2[j].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

            // get the table cell where the buttons go
            var job_box = jobs2[j].getElementsByClassName("col-chk")[0];
            job_box.classList.add("icon");

            // read localStorage for selected job
            var lstore = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("job_" + jid));

            // array for adding buttons
            var arr_acts = ["mail", "accept", "reject"];

            for (var a = 0; a < arr_acts.length; a++) {
                // get the action from the array
                var action = arr_acts[a];
                // create a new span to hold the icon
                var span = document.createElement("span");
                span.setAttribute("data-jobid", jid);
                span.setAttribute("data-action", action);
                span.id = (action + jid);
                span.classList.add(action);
                span.onclick = toggleLocal;
                //span.classList.add("disabled");
                // set the icon for each action
                var icon;
                switch (action) {
                    case "mail":
                        icon = "&#x01f4e7;";
                        break;
                    case "accept":
                        icon = "&#x1F44D;";
                        break;
                    case "reject":
                        icon = "&#x1F44E;";
                        break;
                }
                // if the action doesn't exist in localStorage, set the class to "disabled"
                console.log(lstore);
                // *** this is where the loop breaks *** //
                if (lstore.hasOwnProperty(action)) {
                    span.classList.add("disabled");
                }
                span.innerHTML = icon;
                // render the icon
                job_box.appendChild(span);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: *"the array simply breaks "* - Do you mean that an error occurs there? What does the console show? *"as a JSON object converted to a string*" - [There's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/); JSON is *already* a string format.

Comment: At the end of `switch`, include that condition and the statements that follow it as the `default:` part of `switch`. remove the actual `if` don't use it inside the `switch` of course.

Comment: @nnnnnn - I mean within the JavaScript. I'm taking the JSON from localStorage and using JSON.parse() to interact with it, then JSON.stringify() to save it back to localStorage. I don't see any errors in my browser's JS console when I run this, either.

Comment: @zer00ne - not sure I follow. The IF block after the switch is separate from the switch statement. It needs to run regardless of which item in the array is active.

Comment: @ClairelyClaire nevermind, I noticed the array. If you are running a switch in a `for` to generate the same 3 buttons for every time, why not create the span directly? The array's length is constant so that those 3 buttons always get added on each span. It looks like the loop will go 3 times and go through the switch in the same order of the array each time, there's no variation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've figured this out - my variable calling to localStorage (lstore) is null if nothing exists for that job ID, and that appears to have been breaking my IF statement. This worked:

```js
// if the action doesn't exist in localStorage, set the class to "disabled"
if ((lstore == null) || !(lstore.hasOwnProperty(action))) {
    span.classList.add("disabled");
}
```